# $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2...<i_k\leq n}\frac{4^k}{(i_1+3)(i_2+3)...(i_k+3)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2...<i_k\leq n}\frac{4^k}{(i_1+3)(i_2+3)...(i_k+3)}$$

I have found an alternate version of the problem.
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2...<i_k\leq n}\frac{2^k}{(i_1+1)(i_2+1)...(i_k+1)}$$
Whose solution goes as follows:
Let $a_n$ represent the summation. We have $$a_n=\left(\frac{n+3}{n+1}\right)a_{n-1}+\frac{2}{n+1}$$ for every $n>0$ and $a_0=0$.
This leads to
$$\frac{n(n+5)}{6}$$

I am not able to understand this solution and solve the question at the beginning.

Comment: would the downvoter care to comment? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things get simple once you see that $$\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{1\leqslant i_1<\dots<i_k\leqslant n}\prod_{j=1}^k b_{i_j}=\prod_{k=1}^n(1+b_k)-1.$$

*The provided solution builds a recurrence for the LHS of this equality. Denote it by $a_n$ and assume $n>0$. Now the terms with $i_k<n$ (if any) sum to $a_{n-1}$, the terms with $i_k=n$ and $k>1$ (again if any) sum to $a_{n-1}b_n$, and the remaining term (with $i_1=n$) equals $b_n$. Thus, $$a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-1}b_n+b_n\implies 1+a_n=(1+a_{n-1})(1+b_n).$$*

The case $b_n=2/(n+1)$ results in $$1+a_n=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{k+3}{k+1}=\frac{(n+2)(n+3)}{2\cdot 3}\implies a_n=\frac{n(n+5)}6$$ as expected. Similarly, the case $b_n=4/(n+3)$ leads to $$1+a_n=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{k+7}{k+3}=\frac{(n+4)(n+5)(n+6)(n+7)}{4\cdot 5\cdot 6\cdot 7},$$ or $a_n=n(n+11)(n^2+11n+58)/840$.

Comment: Amazing answer, Thank you!